# Typescript object (type / member) browser (explorer / viewer)

Tags: typescript

I am using VS 2015. For C# it provides "Object browser" window. It is helpful to browse types in assemblies and namespaces, method overloads, etc.

Does any built in or external tool (may be independent application) exist for typescript that can browse a typescript definition files like "Object browser"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, as long as you're using a editor / IDE that supports `Typescript` you should get native support for investigating the types, but you need to install the `typing` for whatever you're working with, e.g.

https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Then you can search `Vue` or `Node` or something and get support for their types usually by

`npm install --save-dev @types/node @types/vue` etc.

Comment: I installed packages with npm. For example I have `rxjs`. There are a lot of `*.d.ts` files in `node_modules/rxjs/` and some have duplicate names (and stored in different folders). So, I am trying to choose an apropriate files for import. IDE supports typescript (shows signatures, F12 navigation to sources, etc.) and works properly without additional typings for rxjs, but I can not find any functionality like "Object browser".

Comment: @AndrewB it would probably be easiest to install rxjs typings as `npm install --save-dev @types/rxjs` then as long as you're using a decent editor / ide it should just work